# C# Byte[] в Image

Tags: c#

Я делаю простое приложение-игру. Она имеет карту.

```
Tile[,] Tiles = new Tile[1000,1000];
Tiles = GetTiles();
```

(Где `Tile` - класс, содержащий три `byte` переменных `R, G, B`).
Мне нужно перевести карту в `System.Drawing.Image` (что бы после сохранить как .png). Гугл подсказал способ.

```
byte[] bytes = GetYourImage();
using(Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
{
    image.Save("output.png", ImageFormat.Png);  
}
```

Однако вскоре я понял, что введя в массив `bytes` три байта, я не получу картинки 1х1 пиксель, ибо кроме цветов, как я и ожидал, файл содержит еще много информации. Помогите решить задачу.

Comment: Не понял, а что ты ожидал?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа.

Первый - использовать метод [Bitmap.SetPixel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Он простой, но работает очень медленно.

```
using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Tiles.GetLength(0), Tiles.GetLength(1), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
{
    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            var tile = Tiles[x, y];
            image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(tile.R, tile.G, tile.B));
        }
    }

    image.Save("output.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Второй способ - использовать [Bitmap.LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Работает в десятки раз быстрее предыдущего.

```
using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Tiles.GetLength(0), Tiles.GetLength(1), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
{
    int width = image.Width;
    int height = image.Height;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    BitmapData bmpData = image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
    {
        int pixel = counter / 3;
        var tile = Tiles[pixel / width, pixel % height];

        rgbValues[counter] = tile.B; // blue
        rgbValues[counter + 1] = tile.G; // green
        rgbValues[counter + 2] = tile.R; // red
    }

    Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
    image.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    image.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам рабочий пример (не забудьте сослаться на WindowsBase и PresentationCore):

```
class Tile
{
    public byte R;
    public byte G;
    public byte B;

    public Tile(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        R = r; G = g; B = b;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"D:\img.png";

    int pixelWidth = 5, pixelHeight = 5;
    var format = PixelFormats.Rgb24;

    Tile[][] data = new Tile[][]
    {
        new Tile[] { new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0) },
        new Tile[] { new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0) },
        new Tile[] { new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0) },
        new Tile[] { new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0) },
        new Tile[] { new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(255, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 0), new Tile(  0, 0, 255) }
    };

    var stride = ComputeDefaultStride(pixelWidth, format);

    var pixels = new byte[stride * pixelHeight];
    for (int y = 0; y < pixelHeight; y++)
    {
        var line = data[y];
        for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
        {
            pixels[y * stride + x * 3 + 0] = line[x].R;
            pixels[y * stride + x * 3 + 1] = line[x].G;
            pixels[y * stride + x * 3 + 2] = line[x].B;
        }
    }

    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(
            pixelWidth: pixelWidth,
            pixelHeight: pixelHeight,
            dpiX: 96,
            dpiY: 96,
            pixelFormat: format,
            palette: null);
    bmp.WritePixels(
            new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight),
            pixels,
            stride,
            0);

    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(path))
        encoder.Save(file);
}

static int ComputeDefaultStride(int width, PixelFormat format)
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride.aspx
    // GDI requires 32-bit stride alignment
    const int BitsInFourBytes = 8 /* bits in byte */ * 4;
    var BitsInRow = width * format.BitsPerPixel;
    return (BitsInRow + (BitsInFourBytes - 1)) / BitsInFourBytes * 4;
}
```